# Functors between categories of equivariant sheaves are equivariant sheaves on the product?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, equivariant-cohomology, geometric-representation-theory

*This is a follow up question to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266259/interactions-functors-between-equivariant-sheaves-for-different-groups) which remained unanswered (satisfactorily) even after a large bounty. I have made a litlle progress and I have no a more specific question which might be easier to answer. I hope that in writing this follow up question I'm not violating any rules. If I am I apologize.*

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups and $X$ and $Y$, $G$ and $H$-sets respectively. The main question is still the following:

> **Question:** What kind of natural functors are there between categories of equivariant sheaves $Sh_G(X) \to Sh_H(Y)$?

Let's work with sheaves of sets and suppose for the moment $X$ and $Y$ points (Let's work with right actions throughout). In this case we're looking for functors: **$G$-Sets $\to H$-Sets**. The general yoga of **functors = bi-modules** gave me the idea to look inside the category of **$G^{op} \times H$-Sets**. Here's a nice step forward:

> There's always a canonical functor
>
> $$G \text{-Sets} \times (G^{op} \times H) \text{ -Sets} \to H \text{-Sets}$$
>
> Which on objects acts by taking the "tensor product" $(A,P) \mapsto A \times_G P$ (note that we modded out by the right action of $G$ on $A$ and the left action on $P$ so now we only have a right $H$ action).

In the case of sheaves of vector spaces ($X$ and $Y$ still points) this is in fact precisely the familiar identification of functors with bimodules if we take the corresponding group algebras.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary $G$ and $H$ sets now. I'd very much like to generalize the above to this situation but am still confused as to how to do so. Ideally I would like the following to hold and to have a concrete description as in the case where everything is a point:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ as before. Every $G \times H$ equivariant sheaf on the product $X \times Y$ gives a pair of natural functors $Sh_G(X) \to Sh_H(Y)$ and $Sh_H(Y) \to Sh_G(X)$. And any interesting functors between these categories is in fact of this type.

Is there a way to make this true?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a discrete group and $X$ a $G$-set. The equivariant category $X//G$ has elements of $X$ as objects, each triple $(g,x,g\cdot x)$ defines a morphism $x \to g\cdot x$, the composition corresponds to the composition of these actions. So e.g. if $X$ is a point, then $X//G$ has a single point $*$ as objects and $Hom(*,*) = G$. If $X=G $ with left action, then $X//G$ has $G$ objects and each pair $x,x' : Ob(X//G)$ is connected by a unique morphism.

**Theorem**: the category of $G$-equivariant sheaves over $X$ is equivalent to the category of presheaves $P(X//G) = [(X//G)^{op}, Set]$.

The category of equivariant sheaves on $X\times Y$ is thus equivalent to $$\begin{eqnarray}
[(X\times Y // G\times H)^{op}, Set] & = & [(X//G)^{op} \times (Y//H)^{op}, Set] \\
& = & \left[(X//G)^{op}, P(Y//H)\right]
\end{eqnarray}$$

Thus if your nice functors are given by $G\times H$-equivariant sets, then their action on $P(X//G)$ is uniquely determined by the action on subcategory $X//G \xrightarrow{Y} P(X//G)$, where $Y$ is the Yoneda embedding. Any presheaf is canonically a colimit of representables, and in fact $P(C)$ is the free cocompletion of $C$ w.r.t all colimits. Thus the interesting functors in your question are really functors preserving all colimits.

**Theorem**: any colimit preserving functor $Sh_G(X) \to Sh_H(Y)$ is represented by $G\times H$-equivariant sheaf on $X \times Y$.

Of course, not all functors preserve all colimits. For example, the right adjoint of any functor defined above will preserve all limits but no colimits in general. So the claim that *all interesting* functors are of this type is a bit thin, but they certainly are the most accessible.

Comment: This was helpful but still slightly off as i'm looking for an explicit construction like the one I describe for the case where everything is a point (notice that my construction easily generalizes to the case of where $G$ topological/algebraic/formal etc. group and could work in principle in any category).

Comment: @SaalHardali Everything that I described is perfectly explicit and generalizes your construction for the point. Note also that your description also works exclusively for colimit-preserving functors (e.g. right adjoint to restriction of scalars isn't included). What exactly is your question?

Comment: The point about the colimit preservation was illuminating thank you. Perhaps I don't understand the answer. As I said I'm looking for the explicit (set-theoretic) consturction which takes a $G$-equivariant sheaf on $X$ and a $G^{op}\times H$ equivariant sheaf and gives an $H$-equivariant sheaf. It might hide somewhere in your answer but I can't spot it.

Comment: @SaalHardali You take a $G$-equivariant sheaf on $X$ and a $G^{op} \times H$-equivariant sheaf on $X\times Y$, take their total spaces (which are $G$ and $G^{op}\times H$ sets respectively), factor their product by the diagonal action of $G$ and consider the projection to $Y$, getting an object in $Sh_H(Y)$. More geometrically you can describe it in Fourier-Mukai style: pull $F:Sh_G(X)$ back to $X\times Y$, multiply it by the kernel and push forward along $X\times Y \to Y$, which amounts to taking fiberwise coinvariants of $G$ action.